# Drush workflow with git

Tags: git, drupal, drush

I've read that when updating Drupal modules with Drush you should first delete the module so that there aren't any orphaned files that could end up causing problems. Is there an automated way to do this with some of the Drush command arguments? I see that some of the SVN related arguments look promising but I'm using git.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot confirm it by reading the Drush code, but I am pretty sure that Drush handles this by itself. It will move the old module directory into a backup-directory and then check out an entirely new version from the Drupal repository.